# Displaying a text behind UIWebView when offline

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I was wondering if there was a method for making a UIWebView see through when it is offline. I want to display a "u need internet for this app" text behind it, so that it shows up when you dont have internet access. Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: @Peter Boesen : Add a label om top of webView center it using autolayout constraint hide the label when you have internet make it visible when you dont have internet thats all :)

Comment: @Arpit I am sorry if i was not clear. no i want to display it when the user doesn't have internet and the web view is not working.

Comment: Create one HTML page that contains text - "U need internet for this app", Now check for internet connection, AND if there is no internet then load that HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to keep watching when network connectivity goes offline. When it is offline, hide the UIWebView and show the UILabel of same size behind it. Do the vice versa, when network is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can download [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) directly from the official apple site but I preefer the swift translation maked by Ashley Mills to his [github page](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) (below a copy of Rechability.swift in case it will be unavailable). You must import this file in your project.

As you can see there are few lines. I make an example to a `UIViewController` but you can realize it to your `UIWebViewController` or wherever you want:

```
let reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(ViewController.checkReachability(_:)), name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability)
        reachability?.startNotifier()
    }

    func checkReachability(note: NSNotification) {
        reachability?.startNotifier()
        if reachability!.isReachable() {
            if reachability!.isReachableViaWiFi() {
                print("∙ reachability via WIFI enabled")
            } else {
                print("∙ reachability via 3G/4G enabled")
            }
        } else {
            print("∙ network is unreachable..")
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No internet", message:"No internet connection available!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
            // Here you can put also a label, or an HTML page to show "no internet connection", do whatever you want to alert your connection status
        }
    }
```

A copy of Reachability.swift :

```
import SystemConfiguration
import Foundation

public let ReachabilityChangedNotification = "ReachabilityChangedNotification"

func callback(reachability:SCNetworkReachability, flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    let reachability = Unmanaged<Reachability>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(info)).takeUnretainedValue()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        reachability.reachabilityChanged(flags)
    }
}


public class Reachability: NSObject {

    public typealias NetworkReachable = (Reachability) -> ()
    public typealias NetworkUnreachable = (Reachability) -> ()

    public enum NetworkStatus: CustomStringConvertible {

        case NotReachable, ReachableViaWiFi, ReachableViaWWAN

        public var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .ReachableViaWWAN:
                return "Cellular"
            case .ReachableViaWiFi:
                return "WiFi"
            case .NotReachable:
                return "No Connection"
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - *** Public properties ***

    public var whenReachable: NetworkReachable?
    public var whenUnreachable: NetworkUnreachable?
    public var reachableOnWWAN: Bool
    public var notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

    public var currentReachabilityStatus: NetworkStatus {
        if isReachable() {
            if isReachableViaWiFi() {
                return .ReachableViaWiFi
            }
            if isRunningOnDevice {
                return .ReachableViaWWAN
            }
        }

        return .NotReachable
    }

    public var currentReachabilityString: String {
        return "\(currentReachabilityStatus)"
    }

    // MARK: - *** Initialisation methods ***

    required public init?(reachabilityRef: SCNetworkReachability?) {
        reachableOnWWAN = true
        self.reachabilityRef = reachabilityRef
    }

    public convenience init?(hostname: String) {

        let nodename = (hostname as NSString).UTF8String
        let ref = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, nodename)
        self.init(reachabilityRef: ref)
    }

    public class func reachabilityForInternetConnection() -> Reachability? {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let ref = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }

        return Reachability(reachabilityRef: ref)
    }

    public class func reachabilityForLocalWiFi() -> Reachability? {

        var localWifiAddress: sockaddr_in = sockaddr_in(sin_len: __uint8_t(0), sin_family: sa_family_t(0), sin_port: in_port_t(0), sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        localWifiAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(localWifiAddress))
        localWifiAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        // IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM is defined in <netinet/in.h> as 169.254.0.0
        let address: UInt32 = 0xA9FE0000
        localWifiAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = in_addr_t(address.bigEndian)

        let ref = withUnsafePointer(&localWifiAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }
        return Reachability(reachabilityRef: ref)
    }

    // MARK: - *** Notifier methods ***
    public func startNotifier() -> Bool {

        if notifierRunning { return true }

        var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
        context.info = UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())

        if SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef!, callback, &context) {
            if SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(reachabilityRef!, reachabilitySerialQueue) {
                notifierRunning = true
                return true
            }
        }

        stopNotifier()

        return false
    }


    public func stopNotifier() {
        if let reachabilityRef = reachabilityRef {
            SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, nil, nil)
        }
        notifierRunning = false
    }

    // MARK: - *** Connection test methods ***
    public func isReachable() -> Bool {
        return isReachableWithTest({ (flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> (Bool) in
            return self.isReachableWithFlags(flags)
        })
    }

    public func isReachableViaWWAN() -> Bool {

        if isRunningOnDevice {
            return isReachableWithTest() { flags -> Bool in
                // Check we're REACHABLE
                if self.isReachable(flags) {

                    // Now, check we're on WWAN
                    if self.isOnWWAN(flags) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    public func isReachableViaWiFi() -> Bool {

        return isReachableWithTest() { flags -> Bool in

            // Check we're reachable
            if self.isReachable(flags) {

                if self.isRunningOnDevice {
                    // Check we're NOT on WWAN
                    if self.isOnWWAN(flags) {
                        return false
                    }
                }
                return true
            }

            return false
        }
    }

    // MARK: - *** Private methods ***
    private var isRunningOnDevice: Bool = {
        #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
            return false
            #else
            return true
        #endif
        }()

    private var notifierRunning = false
    private var reachabilityRef: SCNetworkReachability?
    private let reachabilitySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("uk.co.ashleymills.reachability", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

    private func reachabilityChanged(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) {
        if isReachableWithFlags(flags) {
            if let block = whenReachable {
                block(self)
            }
        } else {
            if let block = whenUnreachable {
                block(self)
            }
        }

        notificationCenter.postNotificationName(ReachabilityChangedNotification, object:self)
    }

    private func isReachableWithFlags(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {

        let reachable = isReachable(flags)

        if !reachable {
            return false
        }

        if isConnectionRequiredOrTransient(flags) {
            return false
        }

        if isRunningOnDevice {
            if isOnWWAN(flags) && !reachableOnWWAN {
                // We don't want to connect when on 3G.
                return false
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    private func isReachableWithTest(test: (SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> (Bool)) -> Bool {

        if let reachabilityRef = reachabilityRef {

            var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
            let gotFlags = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&flags) {
                SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
            }

            if gotFlags {
                return test(flags)
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    // WWAN may be available, but not active until a connection has been established.
    // WiFi may require a connection for VPN on Demand.
    private func isConnectionRequired() -> Bool {
        return connectionRequired()
    }

    private func connectionRequired() -> Bool {
        return isReachableWithTest({ (flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> (Bool) in
            return self.isConnectionRequired(flags)
        })
    }

    // Dynamic, on demand connection?
    private func isConnectionOnDemand() -> Bool {
        return isReachableWithTest({ (flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> (Bool) in
            return self.isConnectionRequired(flags) && self.isConnectionOnTrafficOrDemand(flags)
        })
    }

    // Is user intervention required?
    private func isInterventionRequired() -> Bool {
        return isReachableWithTest({ (flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> (Bool) in
            return self.isConnectionRequired(flags) && self.isInterventionRequired(flags)
        })
    }

    private func isOnWWAN(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        #if os(iOS)
            return flags.contains(.IsWWAN)
        #else
            return false
        #endif
    }
    private func isReachable(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        return flags.contains(.Reachable)
    }
    private func isConnectionRequired(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        return flags.contains(.ConnectionRequired)
    }
    private func isInterventionRequired(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        return flags.contains(.InterventionRequired)
    }
    private func isConnectionOnTraffic(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        return flags.contains(.ConnectionOnTraffic)
    }
    private func isConnectionOnDemand(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        return flags.contains(.ConnectionOnDemand)
    }
    func isConnectionOnTrafficOrDemand(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        return !flags.intersect([.ConnectionOnTraffic, .ConnectionOnDemand]).isEmpty
    }
    private func isTransientConnection(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        return flags.contains(.TransientConnection)
    }
    private func isLocalAddress(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        return flags.contains(.IsLocalAddress)
    }
    private func isDirect(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        return flags.contains(.IsDirect)
    }
    private func isConnectionRequiredOrTransient(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
        let testcase:SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = [.ConnectionRequired, .TransientConnection]
        return flags.intersect(testcase) == testcase
    }

    private var reachabilityFlags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags {
        if let reachabilityRef = reachabilityRef {

            var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
            let gotFlags = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&flags) {
                SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
            }

            if gotFlags {
                return flags
            }
        }

        return []
    }

    override public var description: String {

        var W: String
        if isRunningOnDevice {
            W = isOnWWAN(reachabilityFlags) ? "W" : "-"
        } else {
            W = "X"
        }
        let R = isReachable(reachabilityFlags) ? "R" : "-"
        let c = isConnectionRequired(reachabilityFlags) ? "c" : "-"
        let t = isTransientConnection(reachabilityFlags) ? "t" : "-"
        let i = isInterventionRequired(reachabilityFlags) ? "i" : "-"
        let C = isConnectionOnTraffic(reachabilityFlags) ? "C" : "-"
        let D = isConnectionOnDemand(reachabilityFlags) ? "D" : "-"
        let l = isLocalAddress(reachabilityFlags) ? "l" : "-"
        let d = isDirect(reachabilityFlags) ? "d" : "-"

        return "\(W)\(R) \(c)\(t)\(i)\(C)\(D)\(l)\(d)"
    }

    deinit {
        stopNotifier()

        reachabilityRef = nil
        whenReachable = nil
        whenUnreachable = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**A very simple approach to do so is below:**

1. Create an HTML file which show fancy "No internet connection" text.
   I have created simple html file to show that. HTML filename is `nointernet.html`, add this file to your project.

```
<html>
    <body>

        </br></br></br></br></br></br>
        <p>You need internet connection to use this application.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

2. Implement `UIWebView` delegate methods below:

   ```
   - shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
   - didFailLoadWithError:
   ```
3. Set `webView?.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad` method
4. Now when there is no internet connection, webView's `didFailLoadWithError` delegate method will be called. Write below code to show 'no internet connection' message from HTML file.

   ```
   func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
       return true
   }

   func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
       print("Did fail to load")
       let htmlFilePath : String! = NSBundle.mainBundle() .pathForResource("nointernet", ofType: "html")
       if let htmlString = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFilePath!) {
           webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: hey, been gone for a while, I am quite new, could you maybe explain 2 and 3 in a bit more detail plz :)

Comment: @PeterBoesen: Every control in iOS library has its own delegate methods. Its kind of listener(in context of JAVA). This methods listen for events of control. Same way webView has its own delegate which called when request finish or failed. You'll get more idea from this - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html